# Stored procedure passing parameter

Tags: .net, sql

If I execute a stored procedure with passing parameter it's executing fine.
If I didn't pass a parameter, sometimes it is giving an error. null dataset.

Same sp if I pass with dummy parameter it is returning dataset.

Somebody help me please.

Priya

Comment: can we see some code of the issue?

Answer (score 3):

If the stored procedure declares a parameter that is not optional, you will always need to pass a value to it. If you wish to pass a null value, you should assign [`DBNull.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx) to the parameter before executing it from .NET code.

A parameter is optional if it is given a default value in the declaration, like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spName]
(
    @ParamName varchar(50) = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
  -- procedure code goes here
END
```